How can I make an nginx location block which falls back using a pattern?
I have the following nginx block:
location /fonts/ {
    alias /data/fonts/ofm/;
    try_files $uri =404;
}

I'd like to modify it, such that all missing fonts are served the matching character ranges from Noto Sans.
For example a request to
/fonts/MissingFont/256-511.pbf 

should serve the following file:
/fonts/Noto%20Sans%20Regular/256-511.pbf

Matching on the same /256-511.pbf part is important, this specifies the character ranges.
How can I do it? (I guess by using regex and root instead of alias, but I don't yet see the details. Do I need one or two location blocks? Do I use try_files?)

You can achieve this with a regular expression location block and a try_files statement.
For example:
location ~* ^/font(?<family>/[^/]*)(?<size>/.*)$ {
    root /data/fonts/ofm/;
    try_files $family$size '/Noto Sans Regular$size' =404;
}

try_files will use the decoded name, so %20 is replaced by a space and the parameter enclosed in quotes.
